# PPi 3 no green light only red

Tags: boot

My first RPi 3 was working and then failed.So I purchased a Noobs sd card.No joy. I then bought a second RPi 3 again no joy with either sd card.I downloaded noobs and separately raspbian. No joy again.
My conclusion is that both RPi 3s are kaput., and am reluctant to buy another  without understanding the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: The odds of 2 RPis purchased separately are slim, though certainly not zero. Before giving up, check any components in common. Have you tried a separate known-good, quality power supply? Have you verified that the cards can be read *and written*?

Comment: My vote would go to the power supply or the USB cable.

Comment: If the red light is on steady the power is okay.  If the red light flickers at any point when you plug it in, there is a problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I have checked the voltage on the pin outs and it is 5V + when plugged in to either RPi.

Comment: Yes the res light is steady